# How were the Ryōjin Hishō (Treasured Selection of Superb Songs) authenticated?

Tags: japan, cultural-history, music, classical-japan, proof

The [Ryōjin Hishō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ry%C5%8Djin_Hish%C5%8D) is a collection of songs from the end of the Heian period in Japan, compiled by the emperor [Go-Shirakawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Go-Shirakawa) in 1179. It was notable for focusing songs which were popular at the time, especially among the common people (imayo) as opposed to the the more courtly 'waka' poetry. Only fragments of the Ryōjin Hishō remain, and those that do were recovered (at least in part as Edo era copies) around 1911-1912 by historian Wada Hidematsu and classics scholar Sasaki Nobutsuna. Or at least, that's what I gathered from the book I am currently reading ('[Songs to make the dust dance: The Ryōjin Hishō and Twelfth-Century Japan](https://www.loc.gov/item/93010237/)' by Yung-Hee Kim)

I do find all this supremely fascinating. But I find it curious that the authenticity of the recovered fragments does not seem to ever be in question, or at least discussed (either as an [Edo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo)-era forgery or a modern forgery of an Edo-era copy), in the (admittedly very few) resources I have come across. I do not speak Japanese, so I am clearly missing a lot of data here. But I would have expected that with a copy of such an old document, things would be a lot more uncertain/ambiguous.[Sasaki Nobutsuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobutsuna_Sasaki), who wrote about the findings originally, appears to have been very accomplished in his field, and to me that suggests that he had an expert opinion, but also that other people may have found it difficult to disagree with him. So I am wondering - how was the (extant) Ryōjin Hishō authenticated, that there was no doubt of its provenance?

Extraordinary assertions (such as recovery of documents after 600 years of them disappearing from the record) require extraordinary evidence. Certainly, that evidence exists somewhere! But I do not have access to it, and I am curious. I would love to know more about how writings such as these are dated (language? word usage? specific kanji?).

Comment: Because I feel that extraordinary assertions (such as recovery of documents after 600 years of them dissappearing from the record) require extraordinary evidence. Certainly, that evidence exists somewhere! But I do not have access to it, and I am curious. I would love to know more about how writings such as these are dated (language? word usage? specific kanji?). And this particular set of writings attracted my attention. @MCW

Comment: @MCW Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's not clear to me why you find the discovery of a 600 year old fragment of a unique document to be "extraordinary". Unique historical document fragments are found all the time. One need not doubt the authenticity to ask how it was identified though.